# Android Google Tag Manager doesn't work

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I'm having a problem implementing Google Tag Manager on my project. I have added the library and created the App Id and container file in the Google Tag Manager console, but the app is not registering the events. This is my code:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static final String TAG = App.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        loadTagmanager();
    }

    private void loadTagmanager() {
        final TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);
        tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);
        PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending = tagManager
                .loadContainerPreferNonDefault(CONTAINER_ID, R.raw.gtm_default_container);

        pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
                if (!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "GTM - Failure loading container");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "GTM - Connected");
                }
            }
        }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Method to register events:

```
public static void pushOpenScreenEvent(Context context, String screenName) {
        DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(context).getDataLayer();
        dataLayer.pushEvent("openScreen", DataLayer.mapOf("screenName", screenName));
    }
```